# Pytorch Tabnet classifier to ONNX object

Tags: pytorch, onnx

I am training a pytorch-tabnet model and need to convert it to ONNX for production. ONNX can naturally convert torch.nn.module classes, but the TabNetClassifier is not directly supported. It looks one need to convert TabNetClassifier to torch.nn.module class as the first step.

Any other idea on the conversion is also appreciated.

The regular torch.onnx package is unable to do the conversion as it is expecting a "network" from the model class